# GSA Serving Logs api

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am using GSA Appliance 7.2, I want to access Serving logs by using java code,

Serving Logs we can get by using GSA module Reports-> Serving Logs but I am not able to see any Web Service by GSA to grab this logs (May be I am missing something).

I want serving logs for analyzing detailed query information like 'Number of documents scored for this query' and 'Total time spent in backend'.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to screen scrape it and hit the download link from code as it's not part of the admin API.

[GSA Admin API Documentation v7.2](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/acapi_protocol/acapi_protocol.html)